# I get the following error: "Array subscript is not an integer". but the array is of type int. what do I do wrong?

Tags: c

The deviation function throws me the following error: "Array subscript is not an integer". If you can help me locate the cause of error I'll appreciate it.

```
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #endif
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "stdlib.h"
    #include <stdbool.h>

    //----<< To store matrix cell cordinates >>-------------------------- 
    struct point
    {
      double x;
      double y;
    };
    typedef struct point Point;

    //---<< A Data Structure for queue used in robot_maze  >>---------------------
    struct queueNode 
    { 
        Point pt;  // The cordinates of a cell 
        int dist;  // cell's distance of from the source 
    };

    //----<< check whether given cell (row, col) is a valid cell or not >>--------
    bool isValid(int row, int col, int ROW, int COL) 
    { 
        // return true if row number and column number is in range 
        return (row >= 0) && (row < ROW) && (col >= 0) && (col < COL); 
    } 

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int robot_maze()
    {
        int solution = -1;
        int ROW, COL, i,j;
        Point src, dest;
        scanf("%d", &ROW);
        scanf("%d", &COL);
        scanf("%d %d",&src.x,&src.y);
        scanf("%d %d",&dest.x,&dest.y);
        int arr[ROW][COL],visited[ROW][COL];

        for (i = 0;i < ROW;i++)
        for (j = 0;j < COL;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
            visited[i][j] = -1;
        };

        // check both source and destination cell of the matrix have value 0 
        //if (arr[src.x][src.y] || arr[dest.x][dest.y]) 
        //    return -1; 

        return solution;
    }
```

The "if" statement (behind the //) should just work and enter if both values are 0. notice that I defined the 2D matrix "arr" as type int. why do I get this error?

the problem I try to solve is the "Shortest path in a Binary Maze" problem, but I got stuck at the beginning.

Comment: There are two problems: 1. you didn't read the compiler warnings. 2. Microsoft C doesn't have VLAs, therefore in `int arr[ROW][COL]` and in `visited[ROW][COL]`, ROW and COL need to be constants. Point 2 may not apply on your platform though, you didn't mention what compiler you use. If you don't get any compiler warnings, compile with `-Wall`

Comment: Aside: you would normally `#include <stdio.h>` etc unless you are using local versions.

Comment: I did not get any warnings. I am using Dev-C++5.11. about the #include "stdio.h", my teacher wrote the libraries as a template for all the students, so that's why I use it. should I use malloc to construct 2D array that is depended by the input by the user?

Comment: MSVC gives me four warnings, one for each occurrence. "warning C4477: 'scanf' : format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'double *'". As for the `#include "stdio.h"` it is not wrong: you put that when you want to use your own library instead of the standard library. Note that `#include <stdbool.h>` is the usual way: did the teacher's template use the two different ways to include a library header?

Comment: *`#ifdef _MSC_VER #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS #endif`* – Is pointless since Microsofts compiler won't ever be able to compile your code since it contains a VLA (Variable Length Array).

Comment: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` is probably harmless when *not* using MSVC anyway, so the extra conditional clutters the code.

Answer (score 1):

Read the error carefully: It states `Array subscript is not an integer`. The error in question is because of the values used to access the array's elements.

`src.x`, `src.y`, `dest.x` and `dest.y` are of type `double`. You need to redefine `point` as:

```
struct point
{
  int x;
  int y;
};
```

Or, if you *have* to use `double`, you can cast to `int`.

Comment: OP has other incorrect uses of `double` in the `scanf` calls: `scanf("%d %d",&src.x,&src.y);` and `scanf("%d %d",&dest.x,&dest.y);`.

Comment: This is true, but there *is* a problem with the array too as commented above.